# Unable To Set groupId and clientId when using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am having serious problems dealing with the Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder. There is a lot of ambiguity and consistency issues related the configuration settings for Spring Cloud 3.0.2.RELEASE. I have been trying to set the group ids and the client ids for the Kafka topics, but despite trying out various different combinations, I have not been able to properly configure the group id.

The documentation claims that we should be able to set the group id and the client id by configuring one of the following settings:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding-properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.group
spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.group
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.group
```

None of the above configurations work for setting the client id for producers or group id for consumers. The only progress I have gotten at all was setting the client id through a completely different configuration.

```
spring.kafka.client-id
spring.kafka.admin.client-id
spring.kafka.producer.client-id
```

After setting success setting client id with those settings, I tried setting the group id for the consumers which surprisingly did not work.

```
spring.kafka.group-id   <---- does not exist as a property, but tried this anyway
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id
```

Edit: Here is the application setup.

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public Docket swaggerApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(regex("^(?!.*error).+$"))
        .build()
        .pathMapping("/");
  }
}
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        MyKafkaTopicBinderChannel:
          destination: MyKafkaTopic
          group: MyServiceGroup
      default:
        producer:
          useNativeEncoding: on
        consumer:
          useNativeEncoding: on
        contentType: application/*+avro
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: some.broker.io
          producer-properties:
            key:
              serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
            value:
              serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
            schema:
              registry:
                url: some.registry.io
          consumer-properties:
            key:
              deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            value:
              deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            schema:
              registry.url: some.registry.io
            specific:
              avro:
                reader: true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.some.org</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyService</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>chatbotApi</name>
  <description>Spring Boot Service</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <gson.version>2.8.6</gson.version>
    <springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>
    <swagger-annotations.version>1.6.0</swagger-annotations.version>
    <swagger-models.version>1.6.0</swagger-models.version>
    <jackson-datatype-jsr310.version>2.10.2</jackson-datatype-jsr310.version>
    <avro.version>1.9.2</avro.version>
    <avro-maven-plugin.version>1.9.2</avro-maven-plugin.version>
    <confluent.kafka.version>5.4.0</confluent.kafka.version>
    <kafka-clients.version>2.4.0</kafka-clients.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>confluent</id>
      <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>${gson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson-datatype-jsr310.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>${springfox.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
      <version>${swagger-models.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
      <version>${confluent.kafka.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
      <version>${confluent.kafka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
      <version>${confluent.kafka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>${kafka-clients.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
      <version>${avro.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
      <version>${avro.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>local.yaml</exclude>
          <exclude>avro/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${avro-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>schemas</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>schema</goal>
              <goal>protocol</goal>
              <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/</sourceDirectory>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

SpringIntegrationService.java

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(SpringIntegrationService.KafkaTopicBindings.class)
public class SpringIntegrationService {
  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringIntegrationService.class);
  private MessageChannel someChannel;

  public interface KafkaTopicBindings {
    String MY_KAFKA_TOPIC_BINDER_CHANNEL = "MyKafkaTopicBinderChannel";

    @Output(KafkaTopicBindings.MY_KAFKA_TOPIC_BINDER_CHANNEL)
    MessageChannel someChannel();
  }

  public SpringIntegrationService(KafkaTopicBindings bindings) {
    this.someChannel = bindings.someChannel();
  }

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "entry.kafka")
  public boolean entryKafka(Message<someChannel> msg) {
    logger.info("entryKafka(): Payload: {}", msg.getPayload());

    try {
      return someChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg.getPayload())
          .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "Some Key").build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.warn("entryKafka(): Failed to send message onto someChannel topic", e);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Is it resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [repo](https://github.com/schacko-samples/so-60440415) where I tried to update the application mentioned in the [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-avro-confluent). Cleaned up a few things in the configuration and updated the examples to using the new functional model. I verified that this works. Could you run it on your end and compare with your setup? If you can baseline this sample as a means to report any potential issues, that will help us to further assist you.

Comment: I have tried the code in the repo and it actually works perfectly. Following up with @Oleg Zhurakousky's comment though, it seems like the configuration works perfectly with the reactive programming model will not work if you tried to use Spring Cloud Stream Binder Kafka with Spring Integration.

Comment: For everyone else after me, don't use Spring Integration with Spring Cloud Stream:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_annotation_based_support_legacy

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what doesn't work for you and without seeing a complete sample from you it is impossible to say. So here is a simple example we can use as a starting point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleStreamApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleStreamApplication.class,
                "--spring.cloud.function.definition=uppercase",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.uppercase-in-0.destination=uppercase",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.uppercase-in-0.group=uppercase.group");
    }

   @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
       return v -> v.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

This will result in proper creation/assignment of consumer group. Are you saying the above does not work for you?

Comment: I haven now updated the post. I was also following the guide: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-avro-confluent

Comment: As a beginner in spring-cloud-stream, consider switching to [functional programming model](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function). As you can see, by removing almost all references to annotatioal programming model we've all but  deprecated the approach you are currently using. Also, I've provided you with a simpleest example to get moving, meanwhile you're referencing some blog, which creates a bit of a disconnect as I am not sure what exactly you are looking for to get from this interaction.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware that the content in Baeldung's guide was a deprecated approach. I started out by using Baeldung's guide because it was more detailed on how to get the something up and running. I also noticed that the cleaned up code that was provided by @sobychacko used the reactive libraries. I do love the libraries, but I was afraid of relying on versions of reactive database drivers that are not stable at the moment. I will make the switch to the new paradigm.

Comment: I had missed adding function.definition. This post helped. Thanks :)